# Submit multiple forms with one class on blur (jquery, rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have multiple forms of products in my cart with the same class ('.edit_order_item'). What do I need is to submit the form when I focus out of its field ('.cart-quantity'). This code works only once (for the first field) and has no effect after first fire:

```
$('.cart-quantity').blur(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

I'm using AJAX and Rails:

cart.html.erb:

```
<% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
    <%= render 'carts/cart_row', product: order_item.product, order_item: order_item %>
<% end %>
```

_cart_row.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :color_quantity, value: order_item.color_quantity.to_i, min: 0, class: "form-control cart-quantity" %>
<% end %>
```

HTML code produced by helper:

```
<form class="edit_order_item" id="edit_order_item_192" action="/order_items/192" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
    <input value="0" class="form-control cart-quantity" type="number" name="order_item[color_quantity]" id="order_item_color_quantity" />       
</form>

(x times)
```

What am I doing wrong? What could be the possible solution? Thank you.

UPD
I've just noticed that the form helper produces multiple objects with the same id. Could it be the problem? I'm not referring by id though.

Answer (score 0):

It very well could have to do with there being multiple elements with the same ID. I'd also recommend writing the jQuery a bit differently.

```
$('.edit_order_item').on('blur', '.cart-quantity', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ah1kempw/) for a working demo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Adam.
For some reason this code as well as original is not working even with single id element on a page.
I found an alternative solution: it's fine for me to submit not on focus out but on enter and rails is smart enough to do it out of the box. You must have a submit button though but you can hide it with css.